# Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody MainActivity.java

Tags: java

I've just started writing android apps and i'm following the tutorial on the android developer website but I've come across a syntax error. as I've only just started developing i have no idea how to fix this.

```
package com.example.my.first.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
}
```

Comment: The error message is literally telling you exactly what to add and where to add it...

Comment: Add a `}` at the very bottom of the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error itself saying. Add `}` at end of the class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
}
}  <--- Missing
```

Answer (score 1):

You're simply missing an `}` at the end of your class. (the class `MainActivity` is not closed)